# Por que o hibernate não lista resultados se a consulta select chamar campo null da tabela?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma Classe-Entidade Produto.

```
    @Entity
public class Produto implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(length = 70, nullable = false)
    private String cod;
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String descricao;
    @Column
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUnComer")
    private Unidade unComer;//unidade comercial

}
```

Contudo,
quando faço a query:

```
Select prod.id as id,prod.cod as cod,prod.descricao as descricao,prod.unComer as unComer from Produto prod
```

Ele não lista se não houver unidade comercial salva.Trazendo na consulta somente os valores onde a chave estrangeira foi preenchida.

Já se eu fizer assim:

```
from Produto
```

Ele lista todos os cadastros, tendo chaves estrangeiras null ou não.

Na verdade meu Produto, contém vários outros campos, só que queria listar do banco só alguns que eu preciso.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Estou usando Hibernate 4.3 e mysql 5.6.

Comment: Sua `query` apresenta erros no `stacktrace`, publique na pergunta!?
vc não faz o `prod.descricao` e sua entidade não possui o atributo `partGer` .

Comment: Não gera erros. Simplesmente não lista se tiver null no  atributos relacionais, como unidade comercial.
Para resolver tive que fazer  left join na consulta, sendo que ao chamar prod.unComer já era para fazer. Fica meio redundante, mas foi a solução que tive que fazer `select prod.id as prod, prod.cod as cod, prod.descricao as descricao,prod.unComer as unComer from Produto prod left join prod.unComer as unComer`

Comment: Marlucio Pires. Legal, só adiciona a resposta pra fechar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver tive que fazer left join na consulta, sendo que ao chamar prod.unComer já era para fazer. 
Fica meio redundante, mas foi a solução que tive que fazer
`select prod.id as prod, prod.cod as cod, prod.descricao as descricao,prod.unComer as unComer from Produto prod left join prod.unComer as unComer`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate não trabalha com tipos primitivos (Hibernate, não trabalhar)
Java e tipos primitivos, precisa de converters porque um tipo primitivo nunca será nullo sempre tem um valor padrão

Tente fazer algo

```
public void recebeInt(int value){
System.out.println(value); }
```

Agora chame esse method assim

```
Integer meuInt=null;
recebeInt(meuInt);
```

Veja o que acontece!

Trabalhe sempre com objetos, não tipos primitivos

```
Objeto          Primitivo
Character       char
Integer         int
Long            long
Double          double
```

Comment: Você está dizendo que se no lugar de long eu usasse Long ele traria a unidade comercial sem ter que fazer o left join?

Comment: Sim, se não tiver restrições de consulta ele traz, se não listar é porque suas propriedades de mapeamento do campo estão mapeadas de forma incorreta

Comment: Não mudou em nada... mas vlw a intenção

Comment: Usou no objeto pai e filho?